# <audio> tag compatibility in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

Using the  tag in html I have been able to play music in Google Chrome easily and clicking a link to another song will change the song playing in the player without changing the webpage. The problem is, if I try to do the same in Internet Explorer 11 the controls for the player will not show but the default song still plays. The element is still there as the music will still play and clicking the links will change the song that is playing. Moving the code over into JSFiddle with a simple copy and paste, the controls open in Internet Explorer. [Here is the link](http://jsfiddle.net/4gLGf/5/) Would anyone know how to help fix this?

Here is the code for the audio:

```
<audio id="audio" preload="auto" tabindex="0" controls="" type="audio/mpeg">
    <source type="audio/mp3" src="http://www.archive.org/download/bolero_69/Bolero.mp3">
    Sorry, your browser does not support HTML5 audio.
</audio>
<ul id="playlist">
    <li class="active"><a href="http://www.archive.org/download/bolero_69/Bolero.mp3">Song 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.archive.org/download/MoonlightSonata_755/Beethoven-MoonlightSonata.mp3">Song 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.archive.org/download/CanonInD_261/CanoninD.mp3">Song 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.archive.org/download/PatrikbkarlChamberSymph/PatrikbkarlChamberSymph_vbr_mp3.zip">Song 4</a></li>
```

Comment: so it is working when added to jsfiddle?

Comment: Yes it does work in jsfiddle

Comment: As a general note: According to [**html5test.com for IE 11**](http://html5test.com/compare/browser/ie-11.html) the audio element should be fully supported, though the `Audio Web API` is not. Not sure if that might be adding issues in IE 11 for you later as well or not.

Comment: If I use a singular audio file to play, the audio controls GUI displays for IE11. If I use my code for the multiple files, the area for the audio controls GUI is white but still there. The audio will also still play.

Comment: Unfortunately there are a variety of issues that could cause the audio not to play in IE11, such as content-type, content-disposition, querystrings in the url, cross-domain issues, browser multimedia settings, MS's refusal to support formats such as its own WAV format... the list goes on and on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing the following could help you if you havent done it:

Try wrapping the jQuery within:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    /*scripts*/
});
```

## Entire code as shown in jsfiddle:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> - jsFiddle demo</title>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='/js/lib/dummy.js'></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">
  <style type='text/css'>
  </style>
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
window.onload=function(){
var audio;
var playlist;
var tracks;
var current;

init();
function init(){
    current = 0;
    audio = $('audio');
    playlist = $('#playlist');
    tracks = playlist.find('li a');
    len = tracks.length - 1;
    audio[0].volume = .50;
    playlist.find('a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        link = $(this);
        current = link.parent().index();
        run(link, audio[0]);
    });
    audio[0].addEventListener('ended',function(e){
        current++;
        if(current == len){
            current = 0;
            link = playlist.find('a')[0];
        }else{
             link = playlist.find('a')[current];    
        }
        run($(link),audio[0]);
    });
}
function run(link, player){
        player.src = link.attr('href');
        par = link.parent();
        par.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        audio[0].load();
        audio[0].play();
}
}//]]>  
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <audio id="audio" preload="auto" tabindex="0" controls="" type="audio/mpeg">
        <source type="audio/mp3" src="http://www.archive.org/download/bolero_69/Bolero.mp3">
        Sorry, your browser does not support HTML5 audio.
    </audio>
    <ul id="playlist">
        <li class="active"><a href="http://www.archive.org/download/bolero_69/Bolero.mp3">Song 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.archive.org/download/MoonlightSonata_755/Beethoven-MoonlightSonata.mp3">Song 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.archive.org/download/CanonInD_261/CanoninD.mp3">Song 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.archive.org/download/PatrikbkarlChamberSymph/PatrikbkarlChamberSymph_vbr_mp3.zip">Song 4</a></li>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, I have used that and it allows it to work in Chrome. It's just that the GUI for the audio controls will not be displayed in IE11.

Comment: @Kinexd well if it works in fiddle then the entire code that i added to my answer copy paste it to you page may help

Comment: I updated the jsfiddle page as the first one i uploaded didn't work because I didn't paste everything. The new link I updated in the first post, which is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4gLGf/5/). Could you see if this one with the plain code?

Comment: Sorry dont understand what you are asking in the above comment

Comment: thanks for your help. I copied my code from the developer tools in IE from jsfiddle and somehow it now works in IE11 without jsfiddle. I guess there must have been some error in my code which I must look over.

Answer (score -1):

I found 2 formats,supported by IE11: .m4a and .3ga

also it is possible to rename .3ga to .m4a - it worked.
I found no way to play mp3 in IE11 now